Updating geth on Ubuntu fails
I had some issues with geth and while researching it it was suggested to update get.
Before the update I had
$ geth version
Geth
Version: 1.9.6-unstable
Architecture: amd64
Protocol Versions: [63]
Network Id: 1
Go Version: go1.11.13
Operating System: linux
GOPATH=
GOROOT=/home/travis/.gimme/versions/go1.11.13.linux.amd64

After precisely following the directions here: https://agstakingco.gitbook.io/ethereum-merge-guide-lighthouse-geth/update-geth
I tried again
$ geth version
Geth
Version: 1.9.6-unstable
Architecture: amd64
Protocol Versions: [63]
Network Id: 1
Go Version: go1.11.13
Operating System: linux
GOPATH=
GOROOT=/home/travis/.gimme/versions/go1.11.13.linux.amd64

Any idea why I can't get geth updated?

Close the terminal session in which you’ve updated geth, then reopen a new terminal session and check the version using geth version.
